# mongodb fetching and filtering data -aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collections on mongodb one comments and other is tv shows. I want to fetch comments  of chosen show on its detail page but I keep fetching every comment on collection in detail page -not filtered way basically-. I guess I have to use $lookup operator but I'm not so familiar with it.

```
TvShows.aggregate([{
$lookup: {
From: ‘Comments’,
LocalField: ‘_id’,
foreignField: ‘_id’,
as: ‘TvShow_comments’
}}]);
```

for example at this code how I can get the commented tv shows name or it's id to match it with LocalField in foreignField? I don't understand. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you checked out [$lookup sub-query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection)?

Comment: no I haven't, thanks I will check it out.